# How to rotate two tables and put them on one page

Tags: rotating

I have two wide tables.
What I want to do is rotate the two tables and put them on the same page, one above the other.

*What I have now*:

[image]

*What I want*:

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. In particular, please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) of what you've currently obtained.

Comment: It will be easy to help you if you show us some code to understand how did you do these tables. Please look at https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that

Answer (score 2):

Since you've set the `rotating` tag, I would assume that you're loading the package with that name and are employing one or more `sidewaystable` environments.

If this assumption is correct, just place both `\caption` statements and both `tabular`-like environments inside the same `sidewaystable` environment.

[image]

Here's the code that generated the preceding screenshot (note that I rotated the screenshot, to make it take up less space):

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption} % optional
\begin{document} 

\begin{sidewaystable}
\centering

\caption{AAA}
\begin{tabular}{|*{16}{l|}}
\hline
aaaa & bbbb & cccc & dddd & eeee & ffff & gggg & hhhh & 
kkkk & mmmm & nnnn & oooo & pppp & qqqq & rrrr & zzzz \\
aaaa & bbbb & cccc & dddd & eeee & ffff & gggg & hhhh & 
kkkk & mmmm & nnnn & oooo & pppp & qqqq & rrrr & zzzz \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\vspace{0.5in}  % induce some vertical separation 

\caption{ZZZ}
\begin{tabular}{|*{16}{l|}}
\hline
aaaa & bbbb & cccc & dddd & eeee & ffff & gggg & hhhh & 
kkkk & mmmm & nnnn & oooo & pppp & qqqq & rrrr & zzzz \\
aaaa & bbbb & cccc & dddd & eeee & ffff & gggg & hhhh & 
kkkk & mmmm & nnnn & oooo & pppp & qqqq & rrrr & zzzz \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @SongXiaojia - You're very welcome!

Comment: @Song Xiaojia, you should upvote and accept answer (by click on up-pen and check mark at top left side of the answer). it solve your problem on very elegant way (+1 from me).